# CamlQuery that traverses multiple folders

Tags: 2010, development, caml-query

I've got a `CamlQuery` that traverses the `/public/` folder and returns all files that match a certain criteria and it works gorgeously. Now I need it to do the same for a separate library but have the results returned in the same instance.

**Code**

```
 private static SPListItemCollection retrieveDocs(SPWeb web, String meta)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Key_x0020_Topics'/><Value Type='SPFieldLookupMulti'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
            SPList docLib = web.Lists["public"];
            SPListItemCollection files = docLib.GetItems(query);

            return files;
        }
```

Can I make my query traverse both the `public` and `secure` folder and then return the files as one Collection?

[image: Folders]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, it's possible **only** If there is a relation between the first and second library. so you will be able to use [List Join CAML Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to return the related data from two libraries in one `SPListItemCollection`

---

But I don't think you have this case, so **Alternatively**, you can merge multiple `SPListItemCollection` to a Data Table as the following:

**First,** Define only one function that accepts three parameters with the SPList Object.

```
private static SPListItemCollection retrieveDocs(SPWeb web, String meta,SPList list)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Key_x0020_Topics'/><Value Type='SPFieldLookupMulti'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";

            SPListItemCollection files = list.GetItems(query);

            return files;
        }
```

**Second,** call the function for each list and set each result in an independent site collection.

*First Collection*

```
SPList docLibpublic = web.Lists["public"];
SPListItemCollection  SPLCol1 = retrieveDocs(web, meta,docLibpublic);
```

*Second Collection*

```
SPList docLibsecure = web.Lists["secure"];
SPListItemCollection  SPLCol2 = retrieveDocs(web, meta,docLibsecure);
```

**Now,** Convert each SPListItemCollection to data table then merge the data tables

```
DataTable dtCol1 = SPLCol1.GetDataTable();
DataTable dtCol2 = SPLCol2.GetDataTable();
dtCol1.Merge(dtCol2);
```

**Finally,** you have data table (`dtCol1`) that contains the items from multiple SPListItemCollection

---

> **Note:** You can use [SPSiteDataQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to combine two lists. but unfortunately, the returned collection cannot be parsed to
>   `SPListItemCollection`

Comment: Thanks! is there an easy way now to convert `dtCol1` back into a `SPListItemCollection`?

Comment: @PT_C I stay 2 hours before adding my answer to convert data table to SPListItemCollection but unfortunately, no solution from me or suggested from internet worked for me.